# 10 Virtual Machines with 1 User or 1 Virtual Machine with 10 Users?

Tags: hyper-v, hyper-v-server-2012, hyper-v-server-2012-r2

I have just taken on a client that wants to use Hyper-V and thin-clients together in a 10-client workspace setup.

There is a single server with Windows Server 2012.

Is it better to set up a single Virtual Machine (Win 8 Pro) with 10 simultaneous users or is it better to have 10 Virtual Machines each with a single user?

Other than the additional maintenance/configurations of 10 VMs, what's the downside to multiple VMs instead?

WHat am I missing?

Comment: `Is it better to set up a single Virtual Machine (Win 8 Pro) with 10 simultaneous users or is it better to have 10 Virtual Machines each with a single user? ` - You can't have 10 simultaneous user sessions to a Windows client OS.

Comment: You should probably be looking into using VDI or RDSH.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really depends on what you're trying to accomplish.

In my case, the goal was to simply provide members of the public with a basic desktop experience via thin-clients. Since there was no demand for anything other than Microsoft Office and Web browsing, we decided to go with the Remote Desktop Services model where each thin-client simply remoted into a single, locked-down virtual machine running Server 2012R2.

The original purchaser of the equipment bought Wyse T50s, but in hindsight, I wish he'd purchased Windows Embedded thin clients for simpler centralized management within a completely Windows-based network.

I can see how a full VDI infrastructure would be appropriate for larger-scale operations that require complex application delivery, permission/access rules and the like, but given the simplicity of what we were trying to achieve, Remote Desktop Connections to the Virtual Machine did the job.